# SQL : calculate gaps in roster

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking at finding times where staff are not working for a particular day in a roster. The data in the roster table only shows date,start time and the duration of the shift

The following script shows the date, start and end times of each shift worked for a particular staff member

#### Code:

```
select
date,
convert(time,[start time]) as starttime,
dateadd
(
minute,
duration * 5,
convert(time,[start time])
) as endtime
from roster where date = '2016/08/08' and [staff] = 'ME'  
order by starttime asc
```

#### Results:

> 2016/08/08    00:00:00.0000000    08:00:00.0000000
>
> 2016/08/08    09:00:00.0000000    09:45:00.0000000
>
> 2016/08/08    12:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000

What I would like is

> 2016/08/08    08:00:00.0000000    09:00:00.0000000
>
> 2016/08/08    09:45:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `lead()` function.  You would appear to want:

```
with t as (
      select date,
             convert(time, [start time]) as starttime,
             dateadd(minute, duration * 5, convert(time, [start time])) as endtime
      from roster
      where date = '2016-08-08' and [staff] = 'ME'
     )
select date, endtime, next_endtime
from (select t.*,
             lead(endtime) over (partition by staff order by starttime) as next_endtime
      from t
     ) t
where next_endtime is not null
order by starttime asc;
```